# Import data from excel files with specific file name into another excel sheet

Tags: excel

I need a function/Macro that allows me to import data from files with a specific file name.

More background:
I am downloading a large amount of excel files from an webpage containing Agricultural data for different countries (all files have the same structure in terms of rows and columns). This is done with an Python code that names the files according to a standard of: Country + Crop + Irrigation level + Management level. For instance: GhanaMaizeIrrigationLow.

I have created a excel with drop down menus to select each of these parameters and through the TEXTJOIN function merges it in accordance with the naming of the files.I now need some function/Macro that will import data from specific cells in the file that has the corresponding name. Is there a not too complicated way of doing this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Below is the code that I have used so far, however it imports all files in the folder and I want it only to import the files with a specific name.

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()

Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wsMstr  As Worksheet:   Set wsMstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim fPath   As String:      fPath = "C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\GIS\GAEZ_Downloads\CSV_Files\"    'path to CSV files, include the final \
Dim fCSV    As String

If MsgBox("Clear the existing MasterCSV sheet before importing?", vbYesNo, "Clear?") _
    = vbYes Then wsMstr.UsedRange.Clear

Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro

fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")         'start the CSV file listing

    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
      'open a CSV file
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
      'insert col A and add CSV name
        Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
      'copy date into master sheet and close source file
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy wsMstr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        wbCSV.Close False
      'ready next CSV
        fCSV = Dir
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me, teach me to code, or show me where to start site.  If you have code that does not work, include it in your original post using [edit] and explain what it is doing that is not correct.  If not this will be down voted and closed.

Comment: Okay- Is this better?

Comment: Add an If: `If fCSV like "*namewanted*" then` do your code and end with `End If`